# unpacking * is throwing syntax error on leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, iterable-unpacking

I am solving the coin change problem. I run code on jupyter-notebook with the given example on leetcode and it works.

[image]

The same code does not work on leetcode. causing syntax error:

[image]

Here is the code to copy:

```
def best_sum(target,nums):
    dp=[None for y in range(target+1)]
    dp[0]=[]
    for i in range(len(dp)):
        if dp[i]!=None:
            for num in nums:
                if i+num<=target:
                    combination=[*dp[i],num]
                    if dp[i+num]==None or len(combination)<len(dp[i+num]):
                        dp[i+num]=combination
    return dp[-1]
best_sum(11,[1,2,5])
```

Comment: Any idea what version of Python they're using?  The `*` syntax within a list is allowed in Python 3, but not Python 2.

Comment: @TomKarzes LeetCode identifies two languages `python` and `python3`. The former is obviously Py 2.7.

Comment: @iBug They should add `python2`, and either eliminate `python` or else change it to be equivalent to `python3`, since Python 2 is no longer supported, and inappropriate as a default version of Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your LeetCode language to "Python 3". The unpacking opereator isn't a thing in Python 2.

In case you weren't aware, there are two languages `python` and `python3` available on LeetCode. Obviously `python` refers to Python 2.7.